# Is there a way to get TortoiseHg to pull automatically as changes occur?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, pull

I'm using TortoiseHg for working with a mercurial repository.  I understand that it can be used for offline work which is why this doesn't happen automatically, but...

Q: Is there a way configure TortoiseHg to periodically pull changes or at least pull automatically when it is in use?

My machine is generally at work and the last thing I want to do is to start merging while not having the latest changes only to find that I need to resolve duplicate heads and re-do my work again.

Is there an existing way to tell TortoiseHg that it should keep in sync so that it doesn't fall too far out of sync?  I'm not talking about updating my local respository in any way - I'm just talking about it doing a pull so that it knows the current state of the server's repository as closely as possible.

Please advise - and thanks!
Jeremy

Comment: One option: you could schedule a task for a script that does `hg pull -r branch` that runs in the repo's directory. My solution is to click the "Incoming" button as part of every interaction with tortoise.

Comment: I'm totally with you on the 'click the "Incoming" button as part of every interaction with tortoise'.  I've been showing coworkers how to work efficiently and it involves several places (especially around merges) where I want them to remember to make sure they do a pull (first) and then quickly do their merge work :)

Comment: Just do it the normal mercurial way: install a commit hook which pulls on every commit of yours. And / or alternatively install a merge hook which checks hg incoming and fails, if it's non-empty.